# Constructor takes two Integers and they must not equal, whats the best way to implement this?

Tags: java, oop

```
public MyClass(Integer userId, Integer otherId) {
  if(!userId.equals(otherId)){
    this.userId = userId;
    this.otherId = otherId;
  }
}
```

Thats as far as I got, I want to ensure an instance if never created with matching id's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created another method and made the constructor private, it returns null if matching ids

```
private MyClass(Integer userId, Integer otherId) {
 {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.otherId = otherId;
  }
}
public static  MyClass getInstance(Integer userId, Integer otherId) 
  if(!userId.equals(otherId)){
    return new MyClass(userId,otherId);
  }

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you can't allow the two values to be equal then pretty much your only option it to raise an exception in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I might be completely missing the point of your design, but if you want to create instances of an object with unique ID's that never clash consider using a UUID. Your instances should never have to do a 'circle-jerk' of ID comparisons to make sure none of them are violating the uniqueness constraints.

[Documentation on UUID](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html).

Comment: +1 "'circle-jerk' of ID comparisons" - that **has** to be the first time those words have shared a sentence!

Answer (score 0):

I use another approach, I keep a registry of newly created instances (in an HashSet) and allow instatiation of Objects via a static factory.

```
class User {
  private int _id;

  private static HashSet _instanced = new HashSet();

  public static User getInstance(Integer id) {
    if (_instanced.contains(id)) {
      return null;
    }
    return new User(id);
  }

  private User(Integer id) {
    _id = id.toInt();
  }

  // Getter/Setter for ID
}
```

Since the constructor is private, none will instantiate another User with the same id.

in your methods you could then write

```
User x = User.getInstance(1);
```

Of course this will add one more level to your solution. Still I prefer this kind of approach.

Comment: Looks like a big memory leak waiting to happen to me - and a source of thread problems. I would urge the OP *not* to do this unless they definitely need to.

Comment: I agree, you have to take care of cleaning up when items are no more needed by adding a Dispose() in the User class (java don't has destructors, so you have to manage this things yourself). Used a similar thing in web apps, not much datas around. If numbers gets high, I prefer to have the check in db PKs and managing duplicate insert exceptions. From this point of view Nim answer is a lot better, as usual, it depends. PS: for shortage I've omitted syncro stuffs :)